# JS DOM getAttribute()

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get an attribute value using the DOM and JS, but I can't make the code run. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>

      var x = document.getElementById("sw").getAttribute("src");
      alert("src "+ x);

      document.getElementById("sw").innerHTML ="src "+ x;
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <FORM>
      <IMG id="sw" src="photo.jpg"/>
    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags of your HTML (DOM) is not yet loaded, not yet present at the moment when your JS code is executed. That's why you either need to move you  below your HTML-code like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<FORM>
<IMG id="sw" src="photo.jpg"/>
<SCRIPT>

var x = document.getElementById("sw").getAttribute("src");
alert("src "+ x);

document.getElementById("sw").innerHTML ="src "+ x;
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

or you need to add event handle on DOMLoaded event like so:

```
   <SCRIPT>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

    var x = document.getElementById("sw").getAttribute("src");
    alert("src "+ x);

    document.getElementById("sw").innerHTML ="src "+ x;
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to get attribute of element that is not yet loaded try to put your js inside ready function so it will triggered just after the existence of DOM elements :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sw").getAttribute("src");
    alert("src "+ x);

    document.getElementById("sw").innerHTML ="src "+ x;
});
```

Or you could place your `<script>` code right before the closing tag `</body>`.

Hope this helps.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var x = document.getElementById("sw").getAttribute("src");
        alert("src "+ x);

        document.getElementById("sw").innerHTML ="src "+ x;
      });
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <FORM>
      <IMG id="sw" src="photo.jpg"/>
    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```